# The image of a ring of subsets is not generally a ring. Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory

The following is an exercise from Chapter 1 of Functional Analysis: Vol. I by Berezansky, Sheftel and Us.

> **Exercise 2.6.** Let $f: R_{1} \to R_{2}$ be a mapping and let $\mathfrak R_{1}$ be the ring of subsets of $R_{1}$. Show that, generally speaking, the collection $\{f(A) \mid A \in \mathfrak R_1\}$ of subsets of $R_{2}$ is not a ring.

I was trying to find a counterexample (which is the only way I thought of to show this, is there any other?). My interpretation of $\mathfrak R_1$ is that it is the power set of $R_1$, otherwise, I do not know why they would write "*the* ring of subsets" rather than "*a* ring of subsets." However, with this interpretation, I do not know if a counterexample exists.

Can someone point me in the right direction to either find a counterexample, or correctly interpret this exercise? Thank you.

Comment: Think of the same set with two different rings and the identity map between them.

Comment: For a counterexample, perhaps use the observation that $f(A \cap B)  = f(A) \cap f(B)$ can fail.  Can you make an example using this, where $\{f(A) \mid A \in \mathfrak R\}$ is not closed under intersection?

Comment: @GEdgar I have tried things like this, but had no success. For example, define $f:\{1,2,3\} \to \{1,2\}$ by $f(1) = f(2) = 1$ and $f(3) = 2$. Then, $f(\{1,2,3\}) \cap f(\{1,2\}) = \{1,2\}$ and $f(\{1,2,3\} \cap \{1,2\}) = f(\{1,2\}) = \{1\}$. However, $\{1,2\} = f(\{1,2,3\}) \in \{f(A) \mid A \in \mathfrak R_1\}$. This is the issue I encounter every time; the candidate counterexample happens to be an image of another set in the power set. I think I can get any possible image that can occur via these operations from the power set.

Comment: If $\mathfrak R_1$ consists off **all** subsets of $R_1$, then of course $\{f(A) \mid A \in \mathfrak R_1\}$ is all subsets of $f(R_1)$, so there is no such example.  Thus, I think your interpretation of "the" is wrong.  I think $\mathfrak R_1$ is some ring of subsets of $R_1$, but not necessarily all subsets.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you. I have posted my counterexample as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reading @GEdgar's comment, I believe the correct interpretation of $\mathfrak R_1$ is that it is just *some* ring and not necessarily the power set.

Let $R_1 = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $R_2 = \{0,1\}$ and take $\mathfrak R_1 = \{\{1,2,3,4\}, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \emptyset\}$. Define $f: R_1 \to R_2$ by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x = 1,\\ 1, & x = 2,3,4.\end{cases}$$

Then, $f(\{1,2\}) = \{0,1\}$ and $f(\{3,4\}) = \{1\}$ but $f(\{1,2\}) \setminus f(\{3,4\}) = \{0\} \neq f(A)$ for any $A \in \mathfrak R_1$. Hence, $\{f(A) \mid A \in \mathfrak R_1\}$ is not a ring.